# Laravel send data from controller to middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass token_id and user_id from controller to middleware.
I have some hard time with that.
This is the code that I'm trying to run.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $user_id;
    protected $token_id;

    public function __construct()
{
    $user_id = $this->user_id;
    $token_id = $this->token_id;
    $together = $user_id . ':' . $token_id;

    $this->middleware('check.auth:' . $together);
}

public function setLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        
        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)){
                Secure::checkFailedAuth($request->email, $request->password);
                return response()->json(['response' => false, 'status' => 400, 'message' => 'Provided details are not correct!'], 400);
        }   

        $user = Auth::user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken($user->name);
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        $token->save();

        $this->user_id = Auth::id();
        $this->token_id = $tokenResult->token->token_id;

        return response()->json(['result' => true, 'status' => 200, 'message' => 'Login Successful',  'data' => Auth::user(), 'token' => $tokenResult->accessToken ], 200);
    }
```

When I run that I have no errors, but there is null on both user_id and token_id.
Any ideas why?

Comment: how would the container resolve those 2 ints for you? ... you have to remove them from the constructor ... you are not instantiating this class, the framework is ... where are these 2 variables supposed to come from?

Comment: Yes I did, and there is no bug now, but why I have null on both now?

Comment: because they are `null` (no value was ever set) ... not sure what you are asking

Comment: Well I want to set them to real ids, as you see I'm setting them in setLogin function

Comment: and they wont have a value until that point ... still not sure what you are actually trying to do

Comment: The problem is that I want to pass user_id and token_id when user is logged in to middleware, and I can't do it

Comment: you understand the constructor is ran before any other method call right?  what would this middleware even do that you want to use?  and if they are "logging in" in that method why would you have a middleware checking if they are authenticated?  .... you are going to have to explain what you are "actually" trying to do